# Microsoft Graph API is reporting B2B User already exists but the user is not visible via Azure Portal

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to invite a B2B user to our Azure Active Directory instance. This user already a member of their Azure AD under their own company (separate instance).

I am sending a request to

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations

I get this response:

> { HttpsError: [POST https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/invitations]
>   The user you're inviting already exists in the directory. They can
>   simply sign in into shared apps and resources.

However when I login to the Azure portal, I don't see this users email address. Also, when I try to GET the user via the Graph API, I get this message:

> [GET https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/users/] Resource '' does not exist or one of
>   its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Additionally, user is reporting that they are not able to login using their own login.

Comment: Did the user agree the invitation email?

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure, I'll try to find out. If the invitation has been sent but not accepted, would they exist in our directory?

Comment: Have you tried to filter the user  like `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq '<test@outlook.com>'` ? We cannot get the GUEST user via email via `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<test@outlook.com>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @WayneYang-MSFT I was able to find this users email under a different "userPrincipalName" ! I think this leads me down the correct path, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this guest user should already exist in your tenant.

After invitation, the guest user will be created in the Azure AD. This action won't require user accept.

NOTE: We can use the userPrincipalName to query **the Member** user like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<UPNoftheMember>
```

But we cannot use this to query the guest users. You need to filter **the Guest** user like this:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq '<test@outlook.com>'`

Comment: Hi @Doug Molineux , if this answer is helpful, please kindly mark it as an answer so that we can help more people~ Thanks